# PostgreSQL: What is the major difference while using view and table inheritance?

Tags: postgresql

Q: When to use view and table inheritance in postgreSQL?
Please suggest me with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two concepts don't have much in common.

Start by reading [the manual about views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-views.html) and [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html)